# How to get eliminate ++ in Scala

Tags: scala, function, operators

I have a code in scala that I wrote but I would like to eliminate ++ from it. The code runs fine but I'm trying not to use ++ or any built in functions or operators (not even :::).

Is it just better to create a val, or are there better ways around it.

Here's a sample of that code.

```
def partitionAux[A](f: A => Boolean, lst: List[A], 
                       rslt: (List[A], List[A]) ):(List[A], List[A]) = {
  lst match {
    case Nil => return result
    case head :: rest => {
      if (f(head))
        return partitionHelper(f, rest, (result._1 ++ List[A](head), rslt._2))
      else ...
```

Comment: 1. What (is `partitionAux` supposed to do; give sample input and output)? 2. Why (don't you want to use `++`)?

Comment: It's part of an exercise I am doing. partitionAux is helper method that's supposed to split a list into 2 by checking whether some other function is true or false.

Comment: sample would be if if were to split a list between odds and evens:  List(0,1,3,4,6)) == (List(0,4,6), List(1,3))

Comment: So you want to use `::` instead of `++` (or `:::`)? Simply prepend to the result in your recursive function and then reverse both list at the end. (you should do this even if you could use `++`, as appending to a list is `O(n)`, prepending is `O(1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have only a single element as a second arg of `++`, you could implement it yourself:

```
 def concat[A](lst: List[A], a: A): List[A] =
    lst match {
      case Nil => a :: Nil
      case head :: tail => head :: concat(tail, a)
    }

println(concat(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil, 100)) // 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 100
```

Also given that you mentioned that `partitionAux` should split the list into two, it sounds like you should have just `head :: result._1`, instead of `result._1 ++ List[A](head)`, and then reverse the list in the end. It is easy to write the reverse function yourself, like:

```
@tailRec
def reverse[A](list: List[A], result: List[A] = Nil): List[A] = 
  list match {
    case Nil => result
    case head :: tail => reverse(tail, head :: result)
  }
```

P.S. And you don't need to put `return` keyword in scala. It doesn't do anything in you case

Comment: Not only you don't need to put `return`, you shouldn't.